# Why is my MapKit callout view so small and not showing everything it needs to show?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

**SOLUTION** I just had to apply constraints to make it work:

```
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customCalloutView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
        customCalloutView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customCalloutView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
        customCalloutView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

I did a MapKit integration and finally got my app to show my custom callout view, but for some reason, it is tiny and does not show everything it should show... The title displays fine, but the custom "detailCalloutAccessoryView" (which is loaded from a custom-made .xib file with a few labels, an Image view and a button) is not being displayed correctly.

Here is what I mean:

[image: Screenshot of issue]

Why is my detailCalloutAccessoryView getting cut off ? This is what it should look like:

[image: .xib file]

Any ideas ? How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Show you're code for the callout.

Comment: Please don't answer your own question inside your question. Answer your own question _as an answer!_ Answering your own question as an answer is perfectly acceptable on Stack Overflow, and in a couple of days you can even accept your own answer to close the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION I just had to apply constraints to make it work. This code was placed in my viewForAnnotation method

```
let widthConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customCalloutView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
        customCalloutView.addConstraint(widthConstraint)
        let heightConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: customCalloutView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 200)
        customCalloutView.addConstraint(heightConstraint)
```

Comment: Where did you place this code? In the view controller that has you map or in the detailCalloutAccessoryView?

Comment: Just added an edit to specify which function it was implemented in.